# Background color override within span class "mark"

Tags: css, arrays, background-color

I have a site that uses "marks" as a color coded genetic guide. They are set up via an php array in a config page and there is inline styling for the background color. What I want to do is override one of the marks (darkorange) to show a 2-tone color (yellow/white) rather than a solid orange. (Also need to do this for the chartreuse - blue/white.)

I have this for the css but am not sure how to apply it to just the darkorange mark (via stylesheet or inline), it has no effect currently:

```
span.m_darkorange
{
background-color:yellow;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow 50%, white 0);
}
```

The code on the config page:

```
 $aMarkColors = array("crimson", "darkorange", "gold", "chartreuse", "aqua", "royalblue", "blueviolet", "deeppink", "darkblue", "darkgreen", "darkcyan", "chocolate", "darkgoldenrod", "greenyellow", "orchid", "seagreen");
```

And the code that calls the marks:

```
function GetMarksDiv($nMarks, $sClass)
{
global $bIgnoreRedMarks, $aMarkColors, $aMarkColorTooltips;
$sText = "";
if ($bIgnoreRedMarks)
    $nMarks = 0xFE & $nMarks;
if ($nMarks != 0)
{        
    $sText = $sText . "<div class='$sClass'>\n";
    $nMask = 1;
    $nIndex = 0;
    foreach ($aMarkColors as $sColor)
    {
        $x = $nMask & $nMarks;
        $sTitle = "";
        if ($aMarkColorTooltips && $nIndex < count($aMarkColorTooltips))
            $sTitle = "title='$aMarkColorTooltips[$nIndex]'";
        if ($x)
            $sText = $sText .  "<span class='mark' style='background-color:$sColor' $sTitle>&nbsp;</span>\n";
        $nMask = $nMask << 1;
        $nIndex++;
    }
    $sText = $sText .  "</div>\n";
}
return $sText;
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! This is driving me nuts and I can't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add the *$sColor* value to the span's class:

`<span class='mark $sColor' style='background-color:$sColor' $sTitle>&nbsp;</span>\n`

(Your span will then have two classes, one of them is always mark, the other hast the same name as the color)

You can then overwrite the background of selected spans with specific classes in CSS:

```
span.mark.darkorange{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, white);
}
```

Also: Did you use your browser's console (inspect element) to check what exactly ain't working? They give pretty precise answers. I ask because your CSS isn't valid - the console would definitely have told you that. Maybe there are other mistakes like typos or so...

Comment: I saw the typo in the CSS above... way too tired when I posted! :) I'll try adding the class and changing up the CSS as you suggested. Hopefully that will do the trick.